# Scanning GS1/EAN/UCC-128 barcodes in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, barcode, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-128

So I'm currently working on a project that requires scanning GS1-128 barcodes. So far, for other barcode types, we've been using `AVFoundation`'s scanning without a problem. `AVFoundation` can read Code-128 (which GS1-128 is encoded in); where we're having the problem is that it doesn't look like `AVFoundation` is giving us any of the FNC1 characters to identify which numbers in the barcode are attribute identifiers and which are values, or I'm just missing something. Has anyone had any success with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to scan GS1 databars?

Comment: Same here, did you ever come across this?